# PHP serialize without escaping Quotes

Tags: php, json, serialization

I'm `serializing` and then `json_encoding` an PHP array.

After that, i'm getting this string as result:

```
"a:5:{s:3:\"msg\";s:22:\"Logged in successfully\";s:2:\"id\";i:30;s:8:\"username\";s:5:\"test1\";s:5:\"state\";i:1;s:3:\"poi\";a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:\"state\";i:1;s:3:\"msg\";i:1;}i:1;a:2:{s:5:\"state\";i:1;s:3:\"msg\";i:1;}i:2;a:2:{s:5:\"state\";i:1;s:3:\"msg\";i:1;}i:3;a:2:{s:5:\"state\";i:1;s:3:\"msg\";i:1;}i:4;a:2:{s:5:\"state\";i:1;s:3:\"msg\";i:1;}}}"
```

It's working fine, but i need to get rid of the `\` escaping, is there a possibility to give `json_encoding` such a option or must i do it manually?

I know that it's not valid JSON anymore, but i can't change that. It's a given requirement, as sad as it is.

Comment: So what are you doing: `serializing` or `json_encoding`?

Comment: Both, first the `serializing`, then the `encoding`.

Comment: Given requirement, the json will be send to further usage of third-party software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serialize` will produce a string which contains quotes. If you encode that string into a JSON string, those quotes need to be escaped. You cannot have valid JSON without escaping the quotes. If you get rid of the escape characters, it ceases to be valid JSON.

Comment: Sadly it's a given requirement that i can't change, as said in the comments. But i'll add it into the Question.

Comment: Then it's a brain dead requirement which is unfulfillable. Why does a single *string* need to be JSON encoded in the first place? Are you really in need of *JSON encoding*? Are you sure?

Comment: But i guess that would mean that there is no option for the json_encode to set if it's no valid anymore, so this kind of answers my Question

Comment: If you want a JSON string without the valid JSON syntax, it sounds to me like you mostly just need to wrap `""` around your serialised string. Doesn't make any sense, really.

Comment: Yeah, i'm sure. I'm rebuilding an old project and the response for a given task is exactly in this format. And it's working. However we're not in charge of the third-party software and there's also no way to contact them and change this (sadly)

Comment: Would love to fix their software, then there also wouldn't be any needs for the serialization at all, it's frustrating, but i can't change that.